# Create bootable hfs+ partition for macbook

Tags: debian, boot, osx, uefi, hfs+

I've installed Debian testing on a Macbook Pro (mid 2014) without keeping OS X on the internal SSD. I've used the following GPT partition layout:

1. HFS+
2. EFI on /boot/efi
3. BTRFS on /
4. SWAP on swap

I've heard that the Apple implementation of UEFI is different and only boots from a HFS+ partition instead of the default FAT32 partition, so i decided to create a HFS+ partition. The Debian installer automatically installed Grub 2 to the EFI partition, when i manually issue grub-install to the HFS+ partition, grub-install fails. I'm a bit in the dark about how Fedora/Ubuntu solves this problem, those distributions create a HFS+ partition and get it to boot after the install.

I'd like to avoid using refind because i'm not using OS X anymore. I do however have OS X installed on a SD card.

How can i get my laptop to boot Debian directly without using refind?

Comment: Apple should support a FAT32 `/boot/efi` partition as it's mandatory according to the spec. The spec doesn't ban the use of any other filesystem which is why Apple use HFS+.

Anyway, can you expand your post with the error message from `grub-install`?

Comment: Inspired by your comment i reinstalled debian without a HFS+ partition with just a fat32 EFI partition. After a normal install and then using OS X recovery to bless the grubx64.efi file it worked. weird that it didn't the last time. still, thanks for your help.